# How to create this customized UI?

Tags: iphone, xcode

i m new to iphone development
i want to create a view like this..

1.home screen contains
a. a navigation bar
b.a uiimageview
c.a toolbar(with 4 buttons)

2.new view contains
a.navigation bar with back button which leads to home screen.
b.a UITableView.

3.another table view
with navigation bar leads back to (2nd view)

note i want to load new view with the tool bar button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's excellent. Thanks for the update! Keep us informed on how you're doing with that.

Actually, it would be a disservice to you for us to write your code for you. Why don't you try looking at Apple's sample code on the iPhone Dev Center? It'll answer your question.

You can come back here and post code that you've tried that isn't working.

Probably not the answer you want, but I'm pretty sure you'll benefit more from actually researching the question and trying it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Jordan's answer, the place you want to start is [Getting Started w/ iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/index.html). For the type of code you're talking about, you should then investigate the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). When you've gone through the samples and start having trouble with your own code, the Cocoa/iPhone crowd here at Stack Overflow is incredibly helpful. But a statement of program requirements isn't an SO question.